# Blank page after injecting ui.bootstrap without errors

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, ui.bootstrap

After injecting ui.bootstrap into my module the application is loading a blank page without throwing any errors.

If i remove the injection that page loads fine.

`angular.module('app',['ui.bootstrap'])`

I have all the necessary includes

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/ev2/lib/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ev2/lib/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>`

Comment: because you might not have anything to display in the html. update it to post

Comment: don't expect much help with so little information